# How to version front-end projects?

Tags: frontend, version, versioning, web-frontend, semantic-versioning

[Semantic versioning](http://semver.org/) brings the follow approach:

- MAJOR version when you make incompatible API changes
- MINOR version when you add functionality in a backwards-compatible manner
- PATCH version when you make backwards-compatible bug fixes

However a frontend project doesn't have an API, its doesn't break compatibility of usage, then, what the arguments to change the versions in frontends?

Please, sugestions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Proposal

Given the importance of the installation-requirements of an application to installer-users, I propose that semver be used to version end-user applications using the installation-requirements as the public API with installer-users as the consumers of this API.
In practice, increment the:

•   MAJOR version when you make incompatible API changes (e.g. installer-users have to modify their infrastructure (phone/tablet/PC/web-server/firewall config/etc) in some way),

•   MINOR version when you add functionality in a backwards-compatible manner (e.g. passing additional data to an already-provisioned API or adding any end-user functionality that does not affect the installation-requirements), and

•   PATCH version when you make backwards-compatible bug fixes (e.g. fixing any end-user bug that does not affect the installation requirements).

By treating the installer-users as the consumers of an end-user application, and the installation-requirements as the public API, I believe that semver does make sense and is valuable as a communications mechanism for end-user applications.

https://medium.com/@u_glow/making-sense-of-semantic-versioning-for-end-user-software-applications-a3049d97478b

Comment: all the above is only valid for frontends that are installed. For Web Frontends its makes no sense, especially since the available version(s) are defined on server side. It would make more sense there to use something like Versioning by date and release.